# The derived set of $S=\{ m+ \sqrt{2}n: m,n \in Z \} $ is?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

The derived set of
\begin{equation}
  S=  \{  m+ \sqrt{2}n: m,n \in Z \}
\end{equation} is,
In the same set like if m and n belong to natural numbers it is clear that the derived set is empty as all points are isolated points.
and if m and n belong to rational numbers then maybe I'm not correct I still convinced myself that 'Real numbers' is the derived set as if we take n to be zero still we have a rational number set and that have whole real numbers as the limit points but I'm don't know how to tackle this if m and n as given in the problem.
one more doubt for the same set can we say this set is dense in real numbers or not?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $S$ is such that $\alpha \in S \implies m \alpha \in S$ for all $m \in \Bbb Z$. With that said, it sufficient to show that for all $n \in \Bbb Z$, there exists an $\alpha \in S$ with $0 < \alpha < 1/n$. In order to prove this, consider the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $k\sqrt{2}$ for all $k \in \Bbb Z$ and apply the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: Dear sir, can we say for any real number r (say) the neighbourhood of r contains infinitely many elements of the set S?

Comment: Now I get it, thank you.