# The limit points of the set $S$

Tags: real-analysis

[The set $\{m+n \sqrt{2}: m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \} $ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4183284/516174)
and [the set $\{m-n \sqrt{2}: m,n \in \mathbb{N} \}  $ is dense in the negative reals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1215536/516174)

Let $S=\{m+n\sqrt{2}:m,n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. I have proved that $S$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$ as neither $0$ is in $S$ nor it is a limit point of $S$ (since, $1+\sqrt{2}$ is the smallest element in $S$. But I am not sure that $S$ doesn't have any limit point.

*Question:*  $S$ has limit points or not?

Comment: No, $S$ is closed and discrete. You can compute the minimal distance between two elements of it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ does not have limit points.

Let $\ell\in\mathbb R$. You can show that there are only finitely many elements $s\in S$ such that $s\le \ell+1$. Thus $\ell$ is not a limit point.